# How do I redirect domain1.com request to domain1.com/app on IIS

Tags: redirect, http-redirect, iis-10

I have a angular application hosted on `IIS server` Under `Default web site` with folder name `app`
let say for example my domain name is `domain1.com` and have static ip for e.g `1.2.3.4`

Under my dns configuration i have mapped my domain1.com with ip address 1.2.3.4
this works fine and when i browse my domain1.com it show a default IIS page which is absolutely fine!

My angular application is under `Default web site`.

If i need to browse my `angular` application then i need to browse to `domain1.com/App` OR `1.2.3.4/App`

this is also working as expected!

[image: Angular Application]

**My question is how do i redirect a request my request of `domain1.com` To `domina1.com/App`**

Eg. if a user browse to domain1.com then it should be redirected to domain1.com/App

what i have tried till now!

1) I installed Http redirection on IIS server and added a reroute rule 
ex redirect domain1.com/ to domain.com/app.

but above seems to be not working because it gives a error message `too many time redirect`
when i searched for error it says if you have used `URL REWRITE MODULE` extension it will not work

https://help.duo.com/s/article/4554?language=en_US

2) I tried to add URL redirect to under my DNS console but that does not seems to work.

Comment: Have a look at the solutions provided in the following link https://serverfault.com/questions/411184/how-to-change-default-application-in-a-website-in-iis-7-5-on-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

First, try to install the URL rewrite module from web platform installer or manually from using below link:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

and use the rule:

```
<rule name="test1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain1.com/react1/" />
                </rule>
```

[image]

Note:

use your app name instead of react1.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module